# galaxy note 4 sm910c PIT partition error

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-4

i  tried to flash the latest firmware, but after i press the start button,it says PIT partition error,so i installed a PIT partition for note 4 and then tried,still it says PIT  partition error.....can ypu help mewith it?